# CSS Overlapping issues (a and span tags within li)

Tags: html, css

I have the below navigation bar and have added the RESOURCE HUB link and a startburst built in css. I am trying to get the starburst to sit to the left of the text (on the same line) but instead it is overlapping and making the navigation bar look all wonky. I have tried throwing a lot of mud at the wall to see if anything sticks (including making them block-inline elements) but cannot figure it out. I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<li class="menuItem text">
    <span class="starburst"><span><span><span></span></span></span></span>
    <a href="http://www.verifiedvolunteers.info/" target="vvSite">
      RESOURCE HUB
    </a>
</li>
```

**CSS for starburst:**

```
.starburst {
  display:block;
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  background:#fe0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  rotation:-45deg;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  left:2em;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow:0 0 3em #f00, 0 0 4px #f30;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.starburst span {
  display:block;
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  background:#fe0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(22.5deg);
  rotation:22.5deg;
}
.starburst:hover,
.starburst:hover span {
  background:#fa0;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 8px #fff;
}
.starburst:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(315deg);
  rotation:315deg;
}
```

**CSS for Resource Hub link:**

```
.mainNav-menu .menuItem.text a {
    color: #9D9D9D;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.mainNav-menu .menuItem > a {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    border-right: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

**CSS for li:**

```
.mainNav-menu .menuItem {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

**What finally worked thanks to Nomis!:**

[image]

Comment: You have an error in the <li>'s class attribute. Quote marks don't nest. Also, if the code in the screenshots is important, can you add that to the question? Screenshots of code are useless.

Comment: Sure, and I will fix that right now!

Comment: Code is added to the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `top:2em;` and add a `float:right;` in the `.starburst` style. It should improve your situation.

If you want it to the left, also remove the `left:2em;` and change the `float` to `left`. You'll have to add some space to your link too. If the link overlap your starburst, preventing the animation to launch, just add a `z-index:2;` to `.starburst`.

Here's a snippet :

```css
.mainNav-menu .menuItem {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.mainNav-menu .menuItem.text a {
    color: #9D9D9D;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.mainNav-menu .menuItem > a {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    border-right: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.starburst {
  display:block;
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  background:#fe0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  rotation:-45deg;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow:0 0 3em #f00, 0 0 4px #f30;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  float:left;
  z-index:2;
}
.starburst span {
  display:block;
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  background:#fe0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(22.5deg);
  rotation:22.5deg;
}
.starburst:hover,
.starburst:hover span {
  background:#fa0;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 8px #fff;
}
.starburst:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(315deg);
  rotation:315deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-nav nav">


<li class="menuItem text">
  <a href="http://www.verifiedvolunteers.info/" target="vvSite">
    <span class="starburst"><span><span><span></span></span></span></span>
    
      RESOURCE HUB
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menuItem text">
<a href="http://www.verifiedvolunteers.info/" target="vvSite">
    <span class="starburst"><span><span><span></span></span></span></span>
    
      RESOURCE HUB
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menuItem text">
  <a href="http://www.verifiedvolunteers.info/" target="vvSite">
    <span class="starburst"><span><span><span></span></span></span></span>
      RESOURCE HUB
    </a>
</li></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it now. I am actually trying to get the starburst to the left of the text though. I'll try float-left???

Comment: Unfortunately neither worked. Floating it right moved it out of the link's border and into the LOGOUT link's box.

Comment: Yup, added a line about that !

Comment: I saw you added another fix for the left. Let me try that.

Comment: Man, it's almost there. I added 30px of padding-left to the link but the starburst is overlapping the top-left of the box a bit.

Comment: Added image to original post

Comment: Add a little `margin-top` and `margin-left` to the .starbust and you should be good to go.

Comment: Edited to add a little trick if the original animation is blocked by the link.

Comment: Thank you so much Nomis! I just added the final outcome to the original post. It looks great and I know my boss will be happy.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a way to make it a clickable link? I tried converting it to an anchor tag and the styling went wonky.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to put your starburst inside the already existing link (i suppose that you want it to refer to the same page). You'll have to play a bit with your margin and padding of both elements (`a` and `.starburst`) to make it work as cleanly as before. I edited my snippet's html to show what I mean.